# Transgender teenagers grow out of it 75% of the time

Tags: sexuality, gender, sociology

[Ben Shapiro writes:](http://www.dailywire.com/news/5683/3-facts-about-transgenderism-media-ignored-push-ben-shapiro#modal)

> Suicide Rates Among Transgenders Do Not Decrease Thanks to Sex-Change Surgery. The suicide rates among transgenders do not drop after surgery. 41 percent of transgender people attempt suicide sometime in their life; just 4.6 percent of the rest of the population does. The suicide rate among transgender people who say they are never identified as transgender is still 46 percent. 45 percent of transgender people who undergo hormone therapy attempt suicide – higher than the general transgender suicide rate. **Most Children Grow Out Of Transgender Feelings. Dr. Paul McHugh, former head of psychiatry at Johns Hopkins University, finds that 70 to 80 percent of all children with transgender feelings grow out of it.** This is important because the media has already told parents that children confused about their sex should consider whether they are transgender... Consider the findings of a 2011 Swedish study (not the study Ms. Costello used) published seven years after the 2004 UK review. It looked at mortality and morbidity after gender reassignment surgery and found that people who changed genders had a higher risk of suicide. In this study, all the sex-reassigned persons in Sweden from 1973–2003 (191 male-to-females, 133 female-to-males) were compared to a comparable random control group. The sex-reassigned persons had substantially higher rates of death from cardiovascular disease and suicide, and substantially higher rates of attempted suicide….Gender surgery is not effective treatment for depression, anxiety or mental disorders.

I'm primarily curious about the part that I bolded. If that is true that would really render performing corrective surgery on trans teens a cruel and horrific thing to do. Is this factual? What about the rest of this article?

Comment: Just FYI, "corrective surgery on trans teens" is incredibly rare. Generally, teens are treated not even with corrective hormones but hormone suppressants - drugs that delay physical puberty precisely so that they don't feel pressured into making a decision that they might regret later.

Comment: The quoted section also doesn't actually state that those statistics in the beginning are for Transgender Teenagers, but may be for the general trans population of varying ages. It never states at what age a surgery is occurring either.

Comment: I realized, but this was closed so I didn't bother fixing it.